# why my c++ function refused to return a const reference?

Tags: c++, reference, constants

Let's see the following code:

```
template<class T,class Ref>
class test{
private:
    T data;
public:
    test(const T& x):data(x){};
    const Ref operator*(){
        return data;
    };
}
int main(){
    test<int,int&> t(1);
    *t=2;
    return 0;
}
```

The above code works well. The function `operator*()` should return a const reference`const Ref`,but why it just returned a `Ref`?

Comment: Declaring a const-qualified reference is not the same as declaring a reference to const-qualified object. In C++ references are not rebindable so applying a const-qualifier to a reference is redundant and does not change anything. Just return `T const &` (and probably add const-qualifier for operator itself).

Comment: Also you are probably confused with spiral rules of reading C++ declarations. `int &` is a (not rebindable, so essentially const-qualified) reference to `int`, `const int &` and (proper) `int const &` is a (not rebindable, so essentially const) reference to const-qualified `int`. So if `T` is `int &` then `const Ref` or (proper) `Ref const` would mean `int & const`, not `int const &` or `const int &`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The function `operator*()` should return a const reference `const Ref`, but why it just returned a `Ref`?

Note that for `const Ref`, `const` is qualified on `Ref` (i.e. the reference) directly, not the type being referenced. There's no such things like const-qualified reference, for this case the `const` qualifier is just ignored. That means `const Ref` is same as `Ref` (i.e. `int&`).

[[dcl.ref]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#1)

> Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers
>   are introduced through the use of a typedef-name ([dcl.typedef],
>   [temp.param]) or decltype-specifier ([dcl.type.simple]), in which case
>   the cv-qualifiers are ignored. [ Example:
>
> ```
> typedef int& A;
> const A aref = 3;   // ill-formed; lvalue reference to non-const initialized with rvalue
> ```
>
> The type of aref is “lvalue reference to int”, not “lvalue reference
>   to const int”. — end example ]

Answer (score -2):

Edited: Ok, if you want a compile time error on assignment, you can write it like this:

```
template<class T> 
class test { 
private: 
   T data; 
public: 
   test(const T& x):data(x){};
   const T& operator*() { return data; }
};
int main(){ 
    test<int> t(1); 
    *t=2;    // error
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: @Tonii-xx what exactly do you want to get? A compile error on assignment?